# woocommerce rest api get list of orders by metadata

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, woocommerce, metadata

i want to get all woocommerce orders that _shipping_state meta key be equal to 'THR' meta value
my code is:
rest api v3

```
$data = [
  'page' => 1,
  'per_page' => 20,
  'meta_data' => [
    'key' => '_shipping_state',
    'value' => 'THR'
  ]
];
print_r($woocommerce->get( 'orders', $data));
```

but not working and no error message is displayed And all orders are displayed!
Please guide me if anyone knows the solution

Comment: meta_data isn't a parameter on the orders endpoint? 
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#list-all-orders